# Using Filter or If Else to filter an indicator based on the value in another column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have a sample dataset with 4 indicators (Country, Sitename, Year, Test_type & Number_ofTests). My end goal is to have a dataset with both test_types (Covid & Flu) but only for sites that actually provide Covid testing.

This means that I need all the sites that provide Covid testing but need to filter out the sites that have flu testing but not Covid.

I'm running into issues figuring out how to structure the code, since both "Flu" and "Covid" are under the same column "Test_Type."

I tried this code but ended up deleting missing from "Covid" and keeping all the "Flu" which isn't what I wanted.

> master2 <- master1 %>%
> filter (Test_Type %in% c("Covid") %>%
> drop_na(Number_Tests)

Further clarification: The code should drop Site 112 & 118 since they do not provide Covid testing (number_tests = 0)  and should keep the flu variable only for sites that also provide Covid testing. Just a note: Some sitenames do repeat further on in the dataset

Link to a picture of the dataset structure for clarity:
[image: 1]

Comment: Missing `)` at `filter` part? `master2 <- master1 %>% filter(Test_type  == "Covid") %>% drop_na(Number_ofTests)`

Comment: I have that in the actual code- just forgot to write it here

Comment: Based on your screenshot and code, you have an error on the column name for both `Test_Type` and `Number_Tests`

Comment: If you need to select only `Covid` and remove 112 & 118 from data, try `master1 %>% filter(Test_Type  == "Covid", Number_Tests > 0)`

Comment: The issue is that I need to filter out Flu based on if Covid has a value > 0. Does that make sense? I can further clarify

Answer (score 0):

I would use a filtering join for this. The idea is to filter the data set to return all sites that offer Covid tests. Then we can use a filtering join, like `semi_join()` from `dplyr`. Here's how it works:

```
master1 %>% 
  semi_join(
    master1 %>%
      filter(Test_Type == "Covid") %>%
      select(-Test_Type, -Number_Tests) %>%
      distinct()
   )
```

The `semi_join()` function returns all rows in the first set that have a match in the second set. The second set is filtered to only the distinct sites that offer Covid tests.